# Observing heating issues

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, boost, layout

I'm using this [Boost converter](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic2253.pdf).

Below is the schematic:[image]

Layout:

[image]

The IC, [inductor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/SRP5030T-6R8M/3986086) and diode immediately gets heated up. Any idea why?

Also, there's always a 500 mV drop on the output voltage. For 9 V output, 8.5 V is available when load current goes above 0.5 A.

Any idea why?

Comment: Datasheet specifies that this IC works with 2.2 uH inductor and even lowering it with heavy loads

Comment: @MakePlatanGreatAgain, I tried with 3.3uH inductor. It's still heating. Is my schematic and layout ok?

Comment: I'm not a professional pcb engineer but layout looks close to reference in datasheet. Let's wait for another answers

Comment: We will need to know far far more information in your post to diagnose this then what you've provided. Need to know the load for one, have you tried it at lower currents? Usually it's good to put a few loads on converters, start small, like 10mA and then work your way up. Need to see the switching waveform. Also do you have the inductor equations for the voltages you are running at?

Comment: The datasheet specifically states that a 2.2 μH inductor is required: "the MIC2253 is designed to work with a 2.2μH inductor".  You designed it with a 6.8 μH inductor and then replaced it with a 3.3 μH inductor.  Have you tried a 2.2 μH inductor?

Comment: @vir, I did try it with a 2.2uH inductor but still facing the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty likely that using the wrong size inductor is the problem as I'm not the first to point out. It means you'll burn more energy in the inductor, and that the converter isn't going to see the response it expects and has to work differently. Bear in mind the switching frequency is 1MHz.

That being said if the problem persists after the change, check the voltages at each pin to the converter, particularly the FB pin. If there's something wrong in the assembly then it can cause odd problems that are hard to diagnose. It's worth double checking the component values are what they're supposed to be.
It might also be worth checking the ferrite, and seeing if there's significant voltage dropped accross that.

Your layout looks sensible, but there's only one layer shown. What's worth doing as well, is checking the output voltage compared to a ground point as close to your device as possible, ideally the pins. If there's something wrong with your layout, you might find that there's 9V to the device pin, but only 8.5V to the output connection to ground.

It's worth noting that these sorts of devices are supposed to run warm/hot. It's part of getting a lot of power in a small package, the datasheet lists the overcurrent protection kicking in at 150 degC, and operating curves are shown up to 120, so once your voltages are sorted out I wouldn't worry too much about the heating.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me try the modifications suggested by you and come back. Thank you.